# Which Technology Stack Should I Use for Claims-Aware Applications

Tags: asp.net, wif, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

This is a second attempt with better wording of the problem I'm facing.

I have a simple requirement to implement an application that will allow web applications and standalone services that will be claims-aware (using ADFS). Note that I am talking about windows services in addition to web applications.

Which enabling interoperable technologies should a developer pick?

For the life of me, I can't find a resource that says: to build a claims-aware application **using the latest upcoming frameworks**, install *these* packages.

From a framework point of view, I am talking about the following:

- Microsoft.IdentityModel
- Microsoft.Owin
- System.IdentityModel
- Microsoft.Asp.Net.Identity

Which should I be using? Alpha / Beta packages are fine.

Thank you,
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in .net 4.5 IdentityModel is now part of the core libraries (so it no longer called Microsoft.IdentityModel).

So for your system you would need the following:

1. *System.IdentityModel* for the FederationAuthenticationModule (which intercepts and verifies your SAML token submission) and for the SessionAuthenticationModule (which serializes/deserializes your claims.)

To create the claims that you will send between your applciations you would use:

1. *System.Security.Claims*

as I mentioned these are both in .net 4.5.

Comment: If you know how OWIN and ASP.NET Identity fit in with all this, I'm all ears.

Comment: this is good article from brock allen - http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.IdentityModel is the one you are looking for.

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims for IClaimsIdentity interface.
```

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web for WSFederationAuthenticationModule.

Answer (score 0):

Yup - System.IdentityModel is the way to go.

Refer: [What's New in Windows Identity Foundation 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you are wondering what the difference between WIF 3.5 and 4.5 is, refer:

[Guidelines for Migrating an Application Built Using WIF 3.5 to WIF 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157089%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)